# C# PDF Printing Library

Tags: c#, html, pdf, pdf-generation

Are there any free libraries that would "print" to a PDF without actually having to install a PDF printer on the system.  I want something that can be completely self contained in my application.  The reason I say I want it to "print" is that I've tried and tried to find a solution for directly converting from HTML with CSS to PDF, but it does't seem very possible.  So I want to use the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control to render the page first and then output that rendering to PDF.  I just don't want the user to be required to install a PDFPrinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDFsharp](http://pdfsharp.com/)

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Have you actually done this before...that is a very extensive library... an example of outputting from the WebBrowser control to a PDF would be nice.

Comment: I've used the low-level features of PDFsharp, i.e., printing a line of text at specific x-y co-ordinates. I have no idea about being able to print from a WebBrowser.

Comment: sharpPdf is straight forward to use...

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be free? Last time I looked at [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) it looked quite good, and claims to support css ([here](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf5net/source/3-concepts/g-htmlrender.htm)).

[HTMLDOC](http://www.easysw.com/htmldoc/) should support css at some point, but last time I checked the css stuff was still in beta. And has been for "some time"; I've given up waiting... It isn't .NET, but you can use `Process` to invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.html-to-pdf.net/ - This isn't free but its preety cheap and effective. I am using it now to convert HTML with CSS to PDF. Essentially we display the page to the user and then with a click of a button they can download a PDF of the page.

Comment: I've been though most of the items on this page (Now November 2011), and this is the only one which appears to do a good quality job of HTML to PDF. It leaves text as text and image as image, rather than just screen grabbing the contents of a browser object.

Answer (score 0):

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/ is really excellent. You can see how to use it in the repository at stochfit.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Another tool (not free):  http://www.winnovative-software.com/